# Is this continuous function injective?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

The following question was part of my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to mark 1 option . I am not able to deduce that is it correct on not.

> Let  X= {$(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : a^2+b^2 =1$} and f : X-> $\mathbb{R}
>  $ be a continuous function. Then is f injective or not?

I have given ample time to this option but I am unable to find any contradiction or a function satisfying it. So, with no option left I am posting it here.

Please help!

Comment: $f(x,y)=(42,17)$ is not injective. $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is not injective. On the other hand, $f(x,y)=(y,-x)$ is injective

Comment: Sure you've formulated the question well?

Comment: I think you are missing a condition.

Comment: @Contestosis Ya range of f is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Matematleta Ya range of f is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The range of $f$ cannot be all of $\mathbb R$ since the circle is compact.

Comment: @Matematleta The OP should indeed has written that $f$ is a real valued function, rather than its range is $\mathbb R$. Or that its codomain is $\mathbb R$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $X$ is compact and connected, if $f$ is supposed to be continuous and injective, it would be an homeomorphism from $X$ to a compact interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ of positive length.

Take $a$ in the interior of $I$. $X \setminus \{f^{-1}(a)\}$ is connected. As the image of a connected set under an homeomorphism is connected, $I \setminus \{a\}$ would be connected. A contradiction.

$f$ can't be injective.

Comment: Kindly have a look at edit . Iam really sorry

Comment: Answer updated according to your question update.

Comment: How does injectivity implies that $f^{-1}$ will also be continuous?

Comment: Because the image of any closed subset $U$ of $X$ under $f$ is closed as it is the image of a compact subset of $X$ (any closed subset of a compact is compact).

Comment: @mathcounterexamplex.net Why is $X / f^{-1}(a ) $ is connected ?

Comment: If you take out a point from a circle, you still have a connected set.